# Selenium Webdriver can't find "navigate" element in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to this so it may be obvious, but I am struggling with getting my test to run the "navigate" element. Or Object. Whatever it is. Here is my code:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"

# TEST: Sign up for blog
describe "Blog application" do
  describe "signup to the blog application" do
    it "confirm that a user can successfully signup" do
        driver = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox
        # Go to signup form
        driver.get "https://selenium-blog.herokuapp.com/signup"
        # Fill out and submit form
        username_field = driver.find_element(id: 'user_username')
        username_field.send_keys("user")
```

There's more to this test but it isn't relevant to my question. What am I missing? Do I need to install another gem or driver? I've searched everywhere for this answer and can't find it.

I've also tried running it with:

```
driver.navigate.go
```

and that fails as well. Says it cannot find the "navigate" element.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing initializing of your wanted web driver. However you didn't post your current version of selenium, so I assumed it was last version.
Here is what documentation says about `Selenium::WebDriver`.

```
.for(browser) ⇒ Driver
.for(browser, opts) ⇒ Driver
```

> Create a new Driver instance with the correct bridge for the given browser
> One special argument is not passed on to the bridges, :listener. You can pass a listener for this option to get notified of WebDriver events. The passed object must respond to #call or implement the methods from AbstractEventListener.

So in your case you need to change you driver variable

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
# ...
```

[WebDriver docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver.html#for-class_method)

Comment: Okay, I updated my script and now it is giving me this error:

Failure/Error: driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: Here is what the script looks like now:

`<br>require "selenium-webdriver"<br/>
require "rspec"<br/>

<br/>
# TEST: Sign up for blog
describe "Blog application" do
  describe "signup to the blog application" do
    it "confirm that a user can successfully signup" do
        driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
    # Go to signup form
    driver.navigate.to "https://selenium-blog.herokuapp.com/signup"
    # Fill out and submit form
    username_field = driver.find_element(id: 'user_username')
    username_field.send_keys("user")`

Comment: please post your selenium version. It can be found in Gemfile (if specified) or in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code which should help you

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.navigate.to("https://www.google.com/")
```